# Instagram no Wordpress sem Login (sem utilização de senha)

Tags: wordpress

Preciso colocar o instagram na sidebar de um blog porém o usuário tem seguidor demais e tem medo de perde-los e ser hackeado e por ai.
Tentei explicar, mas de jeito nenhum eles querem colocar a senha para autorizar o plugin.
Tem alguma maneira de eu fazer isso sem logar no instagram do usuário ?
procurei diversos plugins e em todos era obrigatório logar.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Tem jeito sim, avisa ao usuário que ele tem que ter uma senha segura no Instagram, o computador bem protegido e o WordPress bem configurado. Se o que você quer precisa de senha, não vai ter muito jeito de conseguir nada sem ela...

Comment: Simples, diz para o usuário que se ele quer ter essa funcionalidade, ele vai precisar seguir as regras que os criadores dessa funcionalidade exigiram, se ele não quiser seguir essas regras, ele não poderá fazer uso, que é 8 ou 80, não tem meio termo para ele

Comment: Não tem um esquema de OpenId não? Ou de chave de aplicação, tipo as apps do Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

@Eroder, a API do Instagram requer um CLIENT ID e um CLIENT SECRET que são fornecidos no momento que você criar uma aplicação. Para criar uma aplicação, você precisa preencher o seguinte formulário: http://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/

Ao realizar o cadastro de sua app você terá em mãos o seu CLIENT ID e um CLIENT SECRET, a partir disso basta realizar suas requisições.

Existem vendors como o [instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com/) que te ajudam nisso, exemplo de código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: YOUR_USER_ID,
        accessToken: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Você conseguirá o acesso as medias recentes como você deseja caso o usuário não tenha um perfil privado, desta forma você não precisa que o usuário passe o ID e SENHA dele para você.

Answer (score 0):

Eroder,

Tenho utilizado um "concorrente" do Instagram que exibe as imagens e apenas um pequeno link no site. Chama-se [Iconosquare](http://iconosquare.com/promote-widget.php#widget).

Deve haver um método que exiba, através da [API do Instagram](http://instagram.com/developer/), mas meus conhecimentos em API são bem básicos.